# Detour null function

Tags: ida, c++, function-hooking

I've been trying to detour a nullsub, this function is used with log purposes, but as the program is compiled under release flags it got removed and I'd like to restore it.

IDA reports as follow:

```
.text:004BAC10 ; void __thiscall nullsub_2(void *)
.text:004BAC10 nullsub_2       proc near       
.text:004BAC10                 retn
.text:004BAC10 nullsub_2       endp
```

My attempt is to detour this address with my own log function, but Microsoft Detours 3.0 throws **ERROR_INVALID_BLOCK**

I think I get this error as it does not have space to place the jump function, and I don't have any idea how I can fix it.

Comment: Can you share more lines of disassembly after this function?

Comment: Sure, @JasonGeffner ! Here it is: http://pastebin.com/qDMP0yz0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on http://pastebin.com/qDMP0yz0, you have enough space to make this work.

The easiest solution is to patch your target executable such that the data from Virtual Address `0x004BAC10` through `0x004BAC1E` is all `nop`s (`0x90` bytes), and patch in a `retn` (`0xC3` byte) at Virtual Address `0x004BAC1F`.

You'll then be able to detour the function with Microsoft Detours.

If patching the EXE isn't an option, let us know and I can look at Detours to suggest what needs to be changed in the Detours library itself.

Comment: The solution worked like a charm! Thank's 